# Word removal using re results in wrong words being removed

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Given a text "article_utf8" i want to remove a list of words:

```
remove = "el|la|de|que|y|a|en|un|ser|se|no|haber|..."

regex = re.compile(r'\b('+remove+r')\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE)

article_out = regex.sub("", article_utf8)
```

however this is incorrectly removing some words and parts of words for example:

```
1- aseguro becomes seguro
2- sería becomes í
3- coma becomes com
4- miercoles becomes 'ercoles'
```

Comment: I tested it and aseguro was left unchanged.  Python 3.3, input was simply "aseguro" or with some words in front and behind too.  Maybe it's a UTF-related issue?

Answer (score 1):

Technically parts of a word can match a regexp. To solve this you would have to make sure that whatever sequence of letters your regexp matches is a single word and not part of it.

One way would be to make the regexp contain leading and trailing spaces, but words could also be separated with periods or commas so you would have to take those into account too if you want to catch all instances.

Alternatively, you can try splitting the list first into words using the built-in split method (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). Then I would check each word in the resulting list, remove the ones I don't want and rejoin the strings. This method, however doesn't even need regexps so it's probably not what you intended despite being simple and practical.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing, the following will remove the small words in a natural language string, without removing them from parts of other words:

```
regex = re.compile(r'[\s]?\b('+remove+')[\b\s\.\,]', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```